# How can I read and split data from file but Ignoring some data too in Java

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I don't know how to explain this, but I have data like

```
1   John    US  38  24  090921
2   Dave    UK  29  12  043721
3   James   US  31  87  823874
```

The data separated by `tab` and I just want to read my data like this

```
1   John    US  38
2   Dave    UK  29
3   James   US  31
```

How can I do like that in Java? can you show me the sample of codes too? Thank You.

Comment: Read it line by line, split line by tab, and take the first 4 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think this will help you in your case.**

```
BufferedReader in = null;
try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename"));
    String read = null;
    while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] splited = read.split("\\s+");
        for (String part : splited) {
            System.out.println(part); // to read the data is inputted correctly or not
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```